# systemd rejecting with 'more than one ExecStart= setting'

Tags: systemd, redis

I'm trying to write a systemd service file for redis.

Here's my file:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=smp-data-services.target
Description=Redis persistent key-value database
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/eg/share/redis/bin/redis-server
ExecStop=/opt/eg/share/redis/bin/redis-cli
Restart=on-failure
User=eg
Group=eg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

No matter what I do, I keep getting:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload

systemd: redis.service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

I can start redis on the command line with no issue like this:

```
/opt/eg/share/redis/bin/redis-server
```

I've read that redis' daemonized forking process is non-standard, and I should avoid Type=forking or oneshot.

Comment: I had a leftover file for `transmission-daemon` from an earlier configuration in `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf`. Removing the file allowed the service to start.

Answer (score 22):

In the [service] section, you should clean the ExecStart command:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=smp-data-services.target
Description=Redis persistent key-value database
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/opt/eg/share/redis/bin/redis-server
ExecStop=/opt/eg/share/redis/bin/redis-cli
Restart=on-failure
User=eg
Group=eg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This works but is also so counter-intuitive!

Comment: "Cleaning" `ExecStart` must be done even for drop-in files, I just hit it. The solution above work.

Comment: Why this works?  First, multiple `ExecStart=`s can exist.  This begs the question as to where this was previously set, as it wasn't in this unit file, but possibly set by default somehow. 

Next from the docs "If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this option will have no effect."

Comment: Can anyone please explain why "clean the ExecStart command" resolved the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [rrauenza](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/69068/rrauenza), he is right. I have a .conf file in /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d/redis_systemd.conf . Once I removed that, it's almost working!

Answer (score 4):

run `systemctl edit redis`
if Service part has startwith `ExecStart=` line, remove it.

The `ExecStart=` line  cannot be modified with `systemctl edit`

Comment: Your solution is to use 'systemctl edit' because it doesn't work.

Comment: I understood that the `systemctl edit redis` mentioned is to _make sure no `ExecStart=` line is there_ — i.e. check if it is, and if so, remove it. _Then_ proceed to change the main configuration instead.